# Angular.js $watch() not catching update from JS object member from Service

Tags: angularjs

`$watch()` is not catching `return sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp` after the first iteration. I'm not sure why, because I verified the datestamps are changing. Also, after the first iteration....if I click on the view repeatedly, the scope variables and view update with the new information...so it's like `$watch` does work...but only if I click on the view manually to make it work.

'use strict';

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $location, $document) {
    console.log("s");
});

angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('cpuCtrl',   ['$scope', 'sseHandler', function($scope, sseHandler) {
    $scope.sseHandler = sseHandler;
    $scope.avaiable = "";
    $scope.apiTimeStamp = sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp;
    $scope.infoReceived = "";
    $scope.last15 = "";
    $scope.last5 = "";
    $scope.lastMinute = "";

    var cpuUpdate = function (result) {
        $scope.available = result.cpuResult.avaiable;
        $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
        $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
        $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data
        $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
        $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
    }
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        console.log("being caught");
        return sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp},
     function(){
            console.log("sss");
            cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);
    });
}]);


angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('filesystemsCtrl', function($scope, $location, $document) {
    console.log("s");
});

angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('httpPortCtrl', function($scope, $location, $document) {
    console.log("s");
});
```

---

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('sseHandler', function ($timeout) {
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');
    var sseHandler = {};
    sseHandler.result =  { "cpuResult" : { timestamp : '1'}  };
    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
         result = JSON.parse(e.data);
         event = Object.keys(result)[0];
         switch(event) {
             case "cpuResult":
                 sseHandler.result = result;
                 console.log(sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp);
             break;
         }
    });
    return sseHandler;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes in `sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp` happen otuside of the Angular context (in the asynchronously executed event-listener callback), so Angular does not know about the changes.

You need to manually trigger a $digest loop, by calling `$rootScope.$apply()`:

```
.factory('sseHandler', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    ...
    source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            // Put all code in here, so Angular can also handle exceptions
            // as if they happened inside the Angular context.
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
```

---

The reason your random clicking around the app made it work, is because you probably triggered some other action (e.g. changed a model, triggered and `ngClick` event etc) which in turn triggered a $digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your `message` event in the `EventListener` does not start a new digest cycle. In your `sseHandler` try:

```
$timeout(function () {sseHandler.result = result;});
```

Comment: This worked. I thought apply() started a new digest cycle...how does `$timeout` start a new digest cycle?

Comment: `$timeout` starts a new digest cycle implictly. You may also use `$rootScope.$apply()` as ExpertSystem suggested. As you have allready injected `$timeout` in your factory I thought, you may just use that.

Comment: only issue here was that the timeout was causing the variable to be overwritten by other data.